# dojo on.emit "click" and "change" not working in IE

Tags: javascript, file, input, dojo

From the code below, you can see that I'm trying to create an Input Type File Textbox dynamically, then firing the "click" event so the file browser pops ups. Once a file is chosen, the "change" event to read the file.

```
            var i = new TextBox({name:'file',type:'file'});

            on(i.domNode, "change", onChange);
            on.emit(i.domNode, "click", {bubbles:true, cancelable:true});

            function onChange(e){
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    console.log(e.target.result);
                }

                reader.onerror = function(stuff) {
                    console.log("error", stuff);
                    console.log (stuff.getMessage());
                }

                reader.readAsText(i.domNode.files[0]);
            }
```

This works perfectly in Chrome but fails misearbly in IE, without providing any message. I figured it might be the event itself but I also tried "onclick" and "onclick". Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file browser pops up in chrome/safari as it is their default behaviour - you don't have to 'emit' a click event. IE doesn't support firing up a file browser by clicking on the text box.

The user has to click on the button to bring up the file browser.